# Wordpress Slider Loading Issue

Tags: wordpress, slider

I am using a free theme of Wordpress and using the theme's inbuilt slider on homepage, but when I load my website, slider images overtake the full screen and header and footer not showing in initial stage. Please help me out, how can I resolve my problem.

Comment: You need to provide what slider your free theme is using? Which free wp theme is having such issue? Please provide more details in the question to trace the issue and help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your reply ,I am using this wordpress theme , https://wordpress.org/themes/restaurateur/ and in this there is also a issue of white spaces on left side

Answer (score 0):

Restaurateur Theme(i.e. a free wordpress theme) is working perfectly fine as i have cross-checked the same on my localhost.

**Please follow the below steps to get it working:**

1. Install new wordpress on your localhost.
2. Install Restaurateur theme using Appearance > Themes > Add New and search for your theme and install & activate.
3. Once theme is installed and activated, create a new page name it "Home" add multiple images to that page using "Set Featured Image"
4. Go to Settings > Reading, click on "A Static Page" radio button and then select newly created page "Home" as Front page.
5. Now access the front end of the site and you will be able to view the slider perfectly.

Hope this helps!

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your help :)